# Page not rendering component in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to complete Angular's Tour of Heroes guide in Ionic, and i'm running into some problems.

It might be because i'm misunderstanding something fundamental about how Ionic works, but here goes:

I've made a component 'heroes':

[image: My heroes component]

Which exports the HeroesComponent with selector app-heroes:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.scss']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroName = "Regularhero";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

}

I import it in my home page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HeroesComponent} from '../heroes/heroes.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  title = "Tour of Heroes";

}
```

And i try to use the app-heroes component in my home.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <app-heroes>

  </app-heroes>
</ion-content>
```

Which fails, the app compiles and the page tries to load.

However I get the mother of all errors in the console, its a template parse error, stating that I need to verify that app-heroes is a part of the module.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, from my understanding of the angular framework it should work, but for some reason it doesn't. So please help me, it feels like there's some fundamental thing i'm misunderstanding about ionic4/angular

Edit:
As requested here's my app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeroesComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: post your `app.module.ts` too!

Comment: I've added a picture of my app.modules

Comment: Please dont post code as images

Comment: My bad, figured it was the easiest way to make the code readable, i'll edit my question

Comment: how did you generated the project? by using angular cli or ionic cli? coz if you manually try to add the ionic modules to an existing project generated with angular cli, you will end up in trouble!

Comment: I used the Ionic CLI to generate the project, Sunil Singh already helped me fix it and i've marked it as an answer. Thanks for responding so quickly though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to delclare your HeroesComponent in `HomeModule`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [..., HeroesComponent],
  ...
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

Comment: I've added my app.module file, as you can see, i've added it in the declarations

Comment: Declare in `home.module.ts` and remove from `AppModule`